# How to optimize copying large amounts of data in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Details:**

I'm using a Google Apps Script function to copy a large amount of data (over 10,000 rows and 115 columns) from one spreadsheet to another. The function takes about 2 minutes to finish, sometimes even longer. I'm not sure if I'm following the best practices for Google Apps Script, and I'm wondering if this is a normal amount of time for the function to take, given the amount of data being copied. The source sheet doesn't have any formulas only text data. I'm also wondering if usage of getValues() and setValues() is the best possible solution for operations with large sheets.

Additionally, I need to trigger this function in several spreadsheets as often as possible with the minimum charge to the source sheet so that's why the reduction of function time is so crucial to me.

Here is the current code I'm using:

```
function importData() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("source-sheet-id").getSheetByName("2014/2021"); 
  let ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Baza danych"); 

  let sourceData = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  let targetRange = ts.getRange(1, 1, sourceData.length, sourceData[0].length);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceData);
  console.log("Zakonczono kopiowanie - Baza");
}
```

**What I've tried:**

I've looked into Apps Script Best Practises and looked on forums and found that the usage of getValues and setValues is a good practice but I'm still looking to find if there is even more optimal and faster way to transfer data between sheets.

**What I'm expecting:**

I'm hoping to learn if there are any better practices or optimizations I can make to this function to significantly reduce the time it takes to run, given the amount of data being copied. If not I'd like to learn if that's the fastest way possible and the 2 minutes of copying are normal for large data.

Comment: By guessing your situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Wow, that was exactly what I was looking for, now the script runs 4-5x faster than before. Instead of over 2 minutes it takes 25 seconds. I saw articles about API usage but no one was able to explain it to me as simple as you did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, I thought that when Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) When Sheets API is used for your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function importData() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.

  const srcSheetName = "2014/2021";
  const dstSheetname = "Baza danych";
  const dstSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const { values } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(srcSpreadsheetId, srcSheetName);
  // Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.clear({}, dstSpreadsheetId, dstSheetname); // If you want to clear the destination sheet, please use this line.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values }, dstSpreadsheetId, dstSheetname, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  console.log("Zakonczono kopiowanie - Baza");
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use more cells like 10,000,000 cells, [this report (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/04/25/report-handling-10000000-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/) might be useful.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)